# Avoid multiple calls of useEffect in nested navigation using expo router

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-navigation

I am currently trying to make a layout with expo-router with following structure:

- App

  - _layout (Stack)
  - home

    - _layout (Tab)
    - index
    - profile
  - place
  - _layout (Stack)

    - [id] (presentation:'modal')

      - review

        - _layout (Stack)
        - [id]

You get the Idea.

Now following problem:

If I login I'll get redirected to /home/index. Within that component I am running a useEffect hook to do some data fetching. Now that hook is being called twice and I don't know why...

On the other hand if I am routing to /place/1 for example (its a modal overlapping the tab navigation and registered in the parent Stack navigator) and than to review/1 (another stack) useEffect is behaving like expected and running only once. But as soon as I close the modal (place/1) which is in-front of home/index, the useEffect of home/index is being called twice again...

App _layout:

```
<AuthProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white", marginBottom: -35 }}>
        <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" />
          <Stack.Screen name="(modals)/addNewModal" options={{ presentation: "modal" }} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="(modals)/searchForPlaceModal"
            options={{
              presentation: "transparentModal",
              animation: "fade",
              animationDuration: 2000,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="place" options={{ presentation: "modal" }} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="(modals)/mapViewModal"
            options={{ presentation: "fullScreenModal", animation: "slide_from_bottom" }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="home" />
        </Stack>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </AuthProvider>
```

Home _layout:

```
<Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: { height: 90 },
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
      }}
      initialRouteName="index"
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          tabBarAllowFontScaling: true,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused, size }) => (
            <TabBarIcon focused={focused} iconName="search1" labelname="Stöbern" />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="favorites"
        options={{
          tabBarAllowFontScaling: true,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused, size }) => (
            <TabBarIcon focused={focused} iconName="hearto" labelname="Favoriten" />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        listeners={{
          tabPress: (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            router.push("/addNewModal");
          },
        }}
        name="addNewModal"
        options={{
          tabBarAllowFontScaling: true,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused, size }) => (
            <TabBarIcon focused={focused} iconName="pluscircle" customSize={60} labelname="" />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="social"
        options={{
          tabBarAllowFontScaling: true,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused, size }) => (
            <TabBarIcon focused={focused} iconName="team" labelname="Community" />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="profile"
        options={{
          tabBarAllowFontScaling: true,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused, size }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} iconName="user" labelname="Profil" />,
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
```

Its really bugging me.. Hope anyone has a solutions to this. :)

I disabled React StrictMode.

Checked for ParentComponent updates.

Found nothing only that it appears to be happening if I route to a nested navigation stack back and forth....

Here is my index file with the useEffect:

```
import { useFocusEffect, useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { ScrollView, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import QuickSearchBar from "../../src/components/home/quickSearchBar";
import ListingComponent from "../../src/components/home/listingComponent";
import SearchBar from "../../src/components/searchBar/SearchBar";
import React from "react";

export default React.memo(function Index() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);

  function getPermissionAndSetLocation() {
    // let { status, ios } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    // if (status !== "granted") {
    // } else {
    //   let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
    //     accuracy: Device.osName === "Android" ? Location.Accuracy.Low : Location.Accuracy.Lowest,
    //   });
    // }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("index home");
  }, []);

  return (
    <View className="flex-1 bg-white relative">
      <View className=" border-b-gray-100 border-b">
        <SearchBar />
        <QuickSearchBar />
      </View>
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} scrollEnabled>
        <ListingComponent />
      </ScrollView>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => router.push("/mapViewModal")}>
        <View className="bg-darkGrey flex-shrink mx-auto mb-5 px-4 py-2 space-x-2 justify-center items-center flex-row rounded-lg">
          <Ionicons name="map" size={30} color="white" />
          <Text className="text-white">Karte</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
});
```

[![Project structure][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3jes.png

Comment: could you show the code for the `useEffect`?

Comment: Updated the post and included the component.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that this is a issue of expo-router. As found in that current [issue](https://github.com/expo/router/issues/320) on GitHub.

Will be watching their progress and use expo-router when stable.